# Validate input in ngfor

Tags: angular, forms, validation

Below you find the html to a form which contains an input field called 'caseName' and any number of input fields called 'exhibitName'. By clicking on the button 'Add new exhibit' a new exhibit is added to 'newCaseExhibits' thus adding a new input field to the form.

```html
<form #newCaseForm="ngForm">
    <div id="newCaseMenu">
        <div id="newCaseHeader">
            <b>New Case</b>
        </div>
        <div id="newCaseInnerContainer">

            <div class="attrValueContainer">
                <span class="attr-name">Name:</span>
                <input class="attr-value edit" type="text" name="name" 
                 required [(ngModel)]="newCase.name" #caseName="ngModel"/>   
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="(caseName.invalid || nameAlreadyInUse(caseName.model) ) && (caseName.dirty || caseName.touched)" 
             class="attrValueContainer">
                <span class="attr-name"></span>
                <div *ngIf="caseName.invalid">
                    A case name is required.
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="nameAlreadyInUse(caseName.model)">
                   This case name already exists.
                </div>
            </div>

            <div *ngFor="let exhibit of newCaseExhibits; let i = index" >
                <div class="exhibitContainer">
                    <span class="attr-name">Exhibit:</span>
                    <input class="attr-value" type="text" [(ngModel)]="exhibit.name" 
                     required name="{{i}}exhibit" #exhibitName="ngModel">
                </div>

                <div *ngIf="(exhibitName.invalid || exhibitNameAlreadyInUse(exhibitName.model) ) && (exhibitName.dirty || exhibitName.touched))" 
                 class="attrValueContainer">
                    <span class="attr-name"></span>
                    <div *ngIf="exhibitName.invalid">
                        A name is required                    
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="exhibitNameAlreadyInUse(exhibitName.model)">
                        There is already another exhibit with this name.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="button extraMarginTop" (click)="onBtnAddExhibitToNewCaseClicked()">
                Add new exhibit
            </div><br>
            <button class="bottomRight" 
             [class.disabled]="newCaseForm.invalid || nameAlreadyInUse(caseName.model)"
             [disabled]="newCaseForm.invalid || nameAlreadyInUse(caseName.model)"
             (click)="onBtnCreateNewCaseClicked()">
                Create case
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Rigth now the input field for each exhibit is being validated on its own. But how do I check this validation state at the 'Create case' button so the user cant create a case with an invalid exhibit name?

Comment: dont u do it already? ```[disabled]="newCaseForm.invalid || nameAlreadyInUse(caseName.model)"```I would suggest to follow up on a reactiveforms approach, where you are validating in the component. Because complex validation checks can get really messy in a template driven approach. On Submit dont forget to check again wether the form is valid or not, cause the html can be manipulated by a user.

Comment: The problem is that ```newCaseForm.invalid``` is not set to true if one of the exhibitNames is invalid.